# Does glob() always return filepaths using DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR?

Tags: php

I don't have a Windows box to test this on and can't find any documentation about it, so I thought I'd ask:

When I run `glob('/path/to/files/*.txt')` it returns an array like:

```
[
  '/path/to/files/foo.txt'
  '/path/to/files/bar.txt'
]
```

I want just the name of the file, so I do:

```
foreach (glob('/path/to/files/*.txt') as $file) {
    $fileName = substr($file, strrpos($file, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR) + 1);
    ...
}
```

Which determines the filename by finding everything after the last slash. I used DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR instead of '/' because I assume that on windows the array will look like

```
[
  '\path\to\files\foo.txt'
  '\path\to\files\bar.txt'
]
```

Is that true? Can anyone confirm that the constant DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR will always match the separator in `glob()` results?

Comment: With `foreach(glob('c:\\develop\\*')...` I get `c:\develop\Apache24 c:\develop\Java` and so on, but with `foreach(glob('c:/develop/*')...` I get `c:/develop/Apache24 c:/develop/Java` using php 5.6.14/win10 - so I guess the answer is "no" ;-) Have you considered using [pathinfo](http://docs.php.net/pathinfo) or [basename](http://docs.php.net/basename) or spl's [DirectoryIterator](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php)?

Comment: Interesting. What if you did `glob('c:\\develop/*')` that would confuse the hell out of it.

Comment: `c:\develop/Apache24`

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer, as pointed out by VolkerK and Barmar in the comments, is "it doesn't matter" because I should be using php's useful [basename](http://docs.php.net/basename) function instead of string hacks.